# Disabled Layout options on Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I'm trying the elements on a window resizable so I need to add a layout to it, but all the options in qt designer are greyed out

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to select 2 or more elements to unlock those options. Actually they are for a group of elements so that you can add layout to any group of elements.